# Compare values in array and get key/index

Tags: php

i have array:

```
        $array = array(
            3 => array(
                'first' => 'aaa',
                'second' => '111',
                'third' => '!!!'
            ),
            7 => array(
                'first' => 'bbb',
                'second' => '222',
                'third' => '###'
            ),
            9 => array(
                'first' => 'ccc',
                'second' => '333',
                'third' => '^^^'
            ),

        );
```

and three variables:

```
$first = 'bbb';
$second = '222';
$third = '###';
```

or can be array:

```
$data = array(
     'first' => 'bbb',
     'second' => '222',
     'third' => '###'
);
```

I would like get key from $array for these values. In this example should return 7.

How can i compare this array with $first, $second and $third or array $data and get key from $array with these values?

Comment: Loop, compare each value, if they all match, use the current key. It's pretty simple. Please try something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
      $array = array(
        3 => array(
            'first' => 'aaa',
            'second' => '111',
            'third' => '!!!'
        ),
        7 => array(
            'first' => 'bbb',
            'second' => '222',
            'third' => '###'
        ),
        9 => array(
            'first' => 'ccc',
            'second' => '333',
            'third' => '^^^'
        ),
    );

    $data = array(
        'first' => 'bbb',
        'second' => '222',
        'third' => '###'
    );

    foreach ($array as $key => $val1) {
        $arr_diff = array_diff($val1, $data);

        if(empty($arr_diff))
        {
            echo $key;
        }
    }
```

foreach loop will you correct  answer.

Comment: I don't know the reason why some-one down-vote this answer???
What is wrong with this answer??? Please Explain in brief.